# My background images won't load even though everything is correct

Tags: html, css

My background image for the div won't load in even though everything is correct

Take a look at my HTML and CSS!

HTML (image)

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM8uU.png)

CSS (image)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btlC7.png)

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('mountain.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my first site</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">

    </head>
    <body>
      
       <div class="wrapper">

       </div>
  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your image located relative to your `html`?

Comment: check the url for your image, is the image in the root fodler?

Comment: i put the image on my desktop

Comment: heres the location of the image     C:\Users\nuhskywalker\OneDrive\Desktop

Comment: You should place your image in the same folder as your html page. For more readability, put it in a folder like `assets/img/`. Then, in your css class, you do : `background-image: url('assets/img/mountain.jpg');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work unless you put some content inside wrapper like headings and paragraphs etc.

or give the wrapper height in px not in %.So next time if you don't have content inside a div which has a background image always use px.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url('mountain.jpg');
}
```

Comment: thanks dude! been struggling with this since this morning...hope n pray that u have a great life ahead!

Answer (score 1):

The image has to be in the same directory as your css file when you are using `background-image: url('mountain.jpg');`. Additionally the height property is relative to their parent elements when applied in percentage. Make sure your html and body elements are set to `height: 100%;` as well and it will work.

Comment: so i moved the jpg file to the same file that has my .css in it, but where do i set the height of the HTML and elements? do i set it in the head or the body? can u edit my code and show me? it would be really helpful if u could do that

Comment: Add "html, body { height: 100%; }" to your css file.